# OpsCenter Installation error: DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I downloaded the tar.gz file and I'm trying to install Opscenter. I am getting the following error.
ERROR:

```
Trying to download https://opscenter.datastax.com:443/definitions/5.0.1/version.md5
```

resulted in following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "build/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/Definitions.py", line 133, in getNewHash
        DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: address 'opscenter.datastax.com' not found: [Errno -2] Name or service not known.
```

Do I need to have internet access to install Opscenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error should not prevent OpsCenter from working correctly, you just won’t have update information (for cases when you’re running outdated versions of Cassandra or OpsCenter.)

OpsCenter does not require internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to configure OpsCenter to not fetch the updated definition files. Refer to [OpsCenter configuration properties](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/configure/opscConfigProps_r.html) and look for the `[definitions] auto_update` property which you can set to False.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.